# Ошибка, класс не существует, как исправить?

Tags: php, symfony

При создание формы я полям задаю класс.
Вылетает ошибка, классы: TextareaType, ChoiceType, DateTimeType не существуют.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<?php

    namespace App\Form;
    use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
    use App\Entity\Notes;
    use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
    use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
    use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

    class NotesType extends AbstractType
    {
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
     $builder
        ->add('title', TextType::class)
        ->add('description', TextareaType::class)
        ->add('status', ChoiceType::class, [
            'choices' => [
                true => 'Active',
                false => 'Inactive'
            ]
        ])
        ->add('created', DateTimeType::class)
    ;
}

public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults([
        'data_class' => Notes::class,
    ]);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всё правильно, потому что классы `TextareaType`, `ChoiceType` и `DateTimeType` отсутствуют в блоке `use`. Чтобы они были видны внутри данного класса вам нужно импортировать эти псевдонимы имени.

[Подробная информация в документации](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.namespaces.importing.php)

Comment: Да да, я добавлял до этого. use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\BaseType; Но эта строчка горит серым в редакторе.

Comment: @IlyaDrummer, а причём тут `BaseType`? Это совершенно другой класс.

Comment: Теперь я понял. Для каждого типа нужно было добавить свой класс, Спасибо!!!